# Unable to change P4 Sandbox remote server connection settings

Tags: perforce, p4v

I recently restored a P4Sandbox. I am now unable pull from the Central Server: it times out. It is attempting to pull using an old IP address. We recently migrated our P4 depot to a new server. How can I update the connection information so that it pulls from the correct shared server?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to recreate your Remotes on the sandbox, so that they have the correct P4Port value.

You can find more information about the P4Sandbox 'p4 remote' command here:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.3/manuals/p4sandbox/aa_p4sbcmdref.html#1069852

You may also wish to check out our new DVCS product, which replaces P4Sandbox:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/dvcs/

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: I'm having further difficulties:

`p4 remote -p REMOTE_HOST:PORT `
tells me: "Depot 'remote' already exists."

`p4 remote -p REMOTE_HOST:PORT -B remote0 -u MYUSERNAME`
tells me: "Cannot create client p4sandbox-MYUSERNAME-HOSTNAME on central server`

It's not clear to me where to go from here. It seems like this should have worked.

Comment: Any thoughts? Is this an administrative issue?